# Jackson Serialization/Deserialization of java.util.EnumMap Errors

Tags: jackson

When I attempt to serialize and deserialize a `java.util.EnumMap` using Jackson v2.5.0 I receive the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.EnumMap out of FIELD_NAME token
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:835)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:831)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromEmpty(StdDeserializer.java:838)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumMapDeserializer.deserialize(EnumMapDeserializer.java:128)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.EnumMapDeserializer.deserialize(EnumMapDeserializer.java:17)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserializeWithType(MapDeserializer.java:364)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:521)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:248)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:169)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:144)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializerBase.java:957)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:521)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(FieldProperty.java:101)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.BeanPropertyMap.findDeserializeAndSet(BeanPropertyMap.java:285)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:335)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeWithObjectId(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1036)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:172)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:144)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:95)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromAny(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:167)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.UntypedObjectDeserializer$Vanilla.deserializeWithType(UntypedObjectDeserializer.java:494)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.TypeWrappedDeserializer.deserialize(TypeWrappedDeserializer.java:42)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3560)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2679)
    at org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec.decode(JsonJacksonCodec.java:107)
    ... 47 more
```

Does anyone know how to resolve it? I have reviewed the Jackson config options docs, but don't see one that will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you be more specific about your issue, sample code, something you're trying to do, I just put together this sample code using Jackson 2.5.2 and it works fine.

```
public class Test {

public enum STATE{
    NEW, RUNNING, WAITING, FINISHED
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    EnumMap<STATE, String>  stateMap = new EnumMap<>(STATE.class);

    stateMap.put(STATE.RUNNING, "Program is running");
    stateMap.put(STATE.WAITING, "Program is waiting");


    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(stateMap));

}
```

}

The output is:

`{"RUNNING":"Program is running","WAITING":"Program is waiting"}`

Let's check what is different and happy to help.

Regarding deserialization, since `EnumMap` requires the Class type as part of the constructor have you considered to extend it for your type specific Enum, for example:

```
public class MyEnumMap extends EnumMap<Test.STATE, String> {

public MyEnumMap() {
    super(Test.STATE.class);
}
```

}

Then you can extend to deserialize you can just reference `MyEnumMap` in the object mapper:

```
EnumMap enumMap = mapper.readValue("{\"RUNNING\":\"Program is running\",\"WAITING\":\"Program is waiting\"}", MyEnumMap.class);
    enumMap.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

The output of the deserializer is:

`RUNNING
WAITING`

Best,

Jose Luis